# asp.net mvc call view from another project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view

I need some help in a Asp.net mvc 4 c# web aplication.
I have two projects in a solution. The second project needs to call a view from the first project. 
Actualy, I try to call the view using Jquery:

```
$('#divPage').load('page URL');
```

if I put this URL in browser the view is called but occurs an error in request when I call using jquery.
How can I do this?

Comment: Check the link by Darin a little ways down..might point you in the right direction..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164309/asp-net-mvc-3-structure-go-to-view-in-another-project

Comment: are you trying to redirect there or open in a new tab?

Comment: I'm trying to load a page in another one, but the "child page" must be loaded in a specific area and not fill the whole area of his "parent page"

Comment: I can use an iframe but is it better do it using an iframe? Or is it a bad practice doing this way?